# uninitialized constant Rack::Session::Abstract::Persisted to start Rails 5 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting this error while running command    `rails s`

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:90:in `<module:Session>': uninitialized constant Rack::Session::Abstract::Persisted (NameError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:8:in `<module:ActionDispatch>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:181:in `const_get'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:181:in `session_store'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:58:in `block in build_stack'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:13:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:13:in `build_stack'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:504:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `block in app'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `app'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /root/sites/instagramm/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /root/sites/instagramm/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from /root/sites/instagramm/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /root/sites/instagramm/config.ru:in `new'
    from /root/sites/instagramm/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you're using `rack` from two places `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack` and `/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1`.
[Removing that `vendor_ruby`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26974928/895789) (not confirmed) could help. Buy maybe a better choice is to install [rvm](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/README.md#installation) to handle your ruby/gems versions.

Comment: Thanks worked I installed rvm and updated gems one time is working fine now