# can't start default server on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, runtime-error, puma

I'm new in rails. I follow the tutorial on the web of rails. After install `sqlite3`, I try start the server, but I can't. the terminal show me this code

```
invitado@Home:~/blog$ bin/rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/mime.rb:54: warning: already initialized constant Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/mime.rb:49: warning: previous definition of MIME_TYPES was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/file.rb:15: warning: already initialized constant Rack::File::ALLOWED_VERBS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/file.rb:17: warning: previous definition of ALLOWED_VERBS was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/file.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant Rack::File::ALLOW_HEADER
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/file.rb:18: warning: previous definition of ALLOW_HEADER was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/response.rb:23: warning: already initialized constant Rack::Response::CHUNKED
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/response.rb:26: warning: previous definition of CHUNKED was here
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:76:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Rack::Session::Abstract::Persisted (NameError)
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in without_bootsnap_cache
```

> and so on with a lot of lines. If anyone can help me I appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Did your `bundle install` go through without any errors? Also, might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190880/uninitialized-constant-racksessionabstractpersisted-to-start-rails-5-serve).

Answer (score 2):

A better choice is to install rvm or rbenv to handle your ruby/gems versions for your app.
Just follow this link http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html
I think it will help you. :)